# Why I use 'console.log(this)' and the this do not bind to console?

Tags: javascript

Now I have some code:

```
window.testFun = {
   say() {
      console.log(this);
   }
};

window.testFun.say();     //  print say

window.console.log(this); // why not console but window?
```

I am sorry that my English is not very good, but I am actively learning English now, and I hope to be able to actively discuss the code with everyone

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` is defined by the *function `this` is used inside*.

You are using it in the global scope. You are just **passing** it to `log`. It isn't a keyword inside the `log` function itself (which is built into the browser and you aren't looking at the source code for it).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your words have made me understand better